# Counting how many duplicates are in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I count how many times wordToCount are in the phrasesToCheck. And how to put this number to counter variable ?

```
let counter = [];
let wordToCount = ["tomato","cat"];
let phrasesToCheck = ['my cat like potatoes','cat like apple','my golden fish like tomato'];
```

```
counter[0] = 1; //tomato
counter[1] = 2; //cat
```

Comment: the title and body of your question read like two different questions

Comment: how can i fix  this ?

Comment: by determining what your question actually is ... do you want to remove something from an array, or do you want to count something in an array? - I've answered the latter below - hope it helps

Comment: Yes thx  your code is amazing :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let wordToCount = ["tomato","cat"];
let phrasesToCheck = ['my cat like potatoes','my cat like apple','my golden fish like tomato'];
let allwords = phrasesToCheck.join(' ').split(' ');
let counter = wordToCount.map(word => allwords.reduce((acc, v) => acc += v === word, 0));
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: But what if i want to find two words like "my cat" ?

Comment: that's not what you asked - it pays to be specific